# Thermodynamic Bethe ansatz validity

Tags: quantum-field-theory, integrable-systems

The thermodynamic Bethe ansatz (TBA) involves introducing a chemical potential $h$ conjugate to some charge $Q$, and considering the hamiltonian $H-hQ$. Particles with the smallest value of the mass to charge ratio $m/q$ can appear in the ground state when $h>m/q$, and if $h$ is just slightly over this threshold these particles will be very low density. We can use the idea that particles are widely separated in the low density regime to postulate a wave function for the ground state near $h\approx m$, and use this to derive certain integral equations. These integral equations can't be solved exactly but they can be expanded in the limit $h\gg m$ which is a regime we can compare with perturbation theory.

Now I'll quote Evans and Hollowood's review paper on this ([arXiv.hep-th/9508141](https://doi.org/10.48550/arXiv.hep-th/9508141)) for the obvious objection:

> At this point we should remark that in the regime h ≫ m considered above, the Fermi rapidity is large and so the ground-state will contain a large number of particles. It would seem therefore that the system is far from the dilute situation used in our naive derivation of the TBA equations. It is one of the miracles of the TBA that it seems, nevertheless, to be valid for many systems in the deep ultra-violet regime, although the exact reason for this is not understood.

This quote is coming from a paper in 1995. Is it understood now why we can consider the TBA equations at $h\gg m$ even though the derivation assumes $h\approx m$?